# Electrical outlet

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

This is a problem from [NCPC 2005](https://ncpc.idi.ntnu.no/ncpc2005/).  Roy has
an apartment with only one single electrical outlet, but he has a bunch of power strips.
Compute the maximum number of outlets he can have using the power strips he
has.  The number of outlets per power strip is given as input.

It turns out that if the number of outlets of the strips respectively are

$$p_1,  p_2, \dots, p_n$$

then the number of outlets is
$$1 - n + \sum_i p_i$$ ,

or

$$1 + p_1-1 + p_2-1 + \dots + p_n-1$$.

**The input to the *program or function* is a non-empty series of positive integers.**

### Examples

```
2 3 4
> 7
2 4 6
> 10
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> 1
100 1000 10000
> 11098
```

Comment: And I thought you weren't supposed to chain power strips ...

Comment: As far as I can tell my Retina answer is the only answer using unary input. You might want to have a look at the comment discussion there: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71047/electrical-outlet/71062#comment174286_71059 ... If you think that the unary solution is too much of a hack that's not in the spirit of the challenge, I'm happy for you to specify that the input should be in decimal (and will then fix my answer accordingly).

Comment: @PålGD The tied Jelly answer was posted earlier anyway.

Comment: *Because electricity is so expensive, your code should be as short as possible as to avoid using more energy*

Comment: If a space-separated list of unary numbers is okay, how about a **backspace-separated** list of unary numbers?

Comment: @cat Time to dig out the old hamster driven turing machine and mechanical computers.

Comment: @immibis sure, but the output would be treated as the information contained in the byte stream not as what happens to by rendered by your terminal.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Jelly, 3 bytes

```
’S‘
```

Decrement (all), sum, increment. [Try it here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZU-KAmA&input=&args=Miw0LDY)

Answer (score 29):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), 3 bytes

```
 1
```

The trailing linefeed is significant.

Input is a space-separated list of [unary numbers](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary).

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=IDEK&input=MTEgMTExMSAxMTExMTE)

#### Explanation

The code simply removes all spaces as well as the `1` after them from the string. Here is why that works:

Addition in unary is simple: just concatenate the numbers which is the same as removing the delimiters. Decrementing by 1 is also simple: just remove a `1` from each number. We want 1 more than the sum of the decremented inputs though, so we simply only remove the `1`s we find after spaces, thereby decrementing all but the first input.

Comment: I'm wondering if input in unary should be allowed.

Comment: @JanDvorak it is by default, unless the challenge explicitly specifies decimal input. (See the link in the answer.) Doesn't matter though, Jelly is winning anyway.

Comment: @MartinBüttner There's sample data both in this question and the original assignment. Don't you think (unless otherwise stated) that it should be a necessary (though not sufficient) criterion for passing, that the code works with the verbatim sample data?

Comment: @nitro2k01 No (in  that case most answers would probably be invalid). Unless the challenge explicitly specifies one particular input format [we normally assume that lists can be taken in any native list format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/8478). Same goes for number formats (at least unary and taking integers as byte values are allowed by consensus unless the challenge forbids them). It's pretty much impossible to include sample data in every thinkable native input format in the challenge.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Imo, that's not the problem that the recommendation is addressing. What still speaks against this is that (unless I'm mistaken) this doesn't work because unary is a supported or native number format in Retina but it happens to work when you process the string as string data. It's a hack. It's even a clever hack, but I'm still not convinced that's it's according to the rules. If space-separated unary numbers was a native format in Retina in the same way that a list of bytes is a native format in bf, I would agree the recommendation applies and I would have a different opinion.

Comment: For completeness, perhaps its worth adding [to- and from-unary conversion](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQwJCoxCiAxCgooLikrCiQjMQ&input=MiA0IDY), just because it can be done.  Of course a score of 22 is nowhere near as spectacular a 3 ...

Comment: If a space-separated list of unary numbers is okay, how about a **backspace-separated** list of unary numbers?

Answer (score 9):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```
.?<_(@'")>{+.!
```

Unfolded:

```
  . ? <
 _ ( @ '
" ) > { +
 . ! . .
  . . .
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAuID8gPAogXyAoIEAgJwoiICkgPiB7ICsKIC4gISAuIC4KICAuIC4gLg&input=MiA0IDY)

I don't think side-length 2 is possible, but there <s>must</s> might be a more efficient side-length 3 solution that this.

This is the usual "decrement all, sum, increment" approach, but I'll have to add diagrams later to show how exactly it works in Hexagony.

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 24 bytes

```py
lambda*n:1-len(n)+sum(n)
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/DTMBwR)

Comment: This assumes that the function is first assigned, then applied to the input from other variable.

Comment: @juandesant ...which is perfectly fine. It's a function literal, which is a valid form of submission.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 9 bytes

```
Tr[#-1]+1&
```

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
foldl1$(+).pred
```

Usage example: `( foldl1$(+).pred ) [2,4,6]` -> `10`.

Old version, different approach, 17 bytes: `succ.sum.map pred`.

Answer (score 6):

## J, 6 bytes

```
+/+1-#
```

Sum plus one minus length. Parenthesize and apply it, like so:

```
   (+/+1-#) 2 3 4
7
```

Answer (score 6):

### [Labyrinth](http://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 9 bytes

```
"?;)!@
+(
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=Ij87KSFACiso&input=MiA0IDY)

The usual primer:

- Labyrinth is 2D and stack-based. Stacks have an infinite number of zeroes on the bottom.
- When the instruction pointer reaches a junction, it checks the top of the stack to determine where to turn next. Negative is left, zero is forward and positive is right.

Here we start at the top left `"`, a no-op, heading rightward. Next is `?`, which reads an int from STDIN (throwing away chars it can't parse as an integer, e.g. spaces). Now we have two cases:

If the input is positive, we turn right, performing:

```
(            decrement top of stack
+            add top two stack elements
             [continue loop]
```

If the input is zero (which occurs at EOF), we go straight ahead, performing:

```
;            pop zero from EOF
)            increment top of stack
!            output top of stack as number
@            halt program
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
hstMQ
```

increment(sum(map(decrement, input)))

Answer (score 5):

### ES6, 25 bytes

```
a=>a.map(n=>r+=n-1,r=1)|r
```

Comment: I was going to post: "One of the rare cases when reduce wins the game" ... and it's 25 too `l=>l.reduce((a,b)=>a+b-1)`.

Comment: @edc65 Yeah, the `(,b)` is costly, but I like that version too.

Answer (score 5):

## MATL, 3 bytes

```
qsQ
```

[Try it online.](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cXNR&input=WzIsMyw0XQ)

### Explanation

```
qsQ
q      thread decrement over the input array
  s    sum
   Q   increment
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
, + '`      + ** `, +'*.
```

Expects newline-separated integers. [Try it online!](http://starry.tryitonline.net/#code=LCArICdgICAgICAgKyAqKiBgLCArJyou&input=MTAwCjEwMDAKMTAwMDA)

Thanks to @MartinBüttner for -2 bytes.

```
,           Read line as integer
 + '        Dupe and jump to label 1 if nonzero
`           Set label 0
      +     Push 1
 *          Sub
*           Add
 `          Set label 1
,           Read line as integer
 + '        Dupe and jump to label 0 if nonzero
*           Add
.           Output as integer
```

The loop is unrolled so that the first number is not decremented, negating the need to increment. Pushing numbers is expensive in Starry...

Comment: I count only 20 bytes.

Comment: @VoteToClose Did you count the leading spaces? (I'm assuming you're talking about the 26 byte)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Code:

```
E<O>
```

Explanation:

```
E     # Evaluates input
 <    # Decrement on list
  O   # Compute the total sum
   >  # Increment on the sum
      # Implicit: output top of the stack
```

Takes input like an array (e.g. `[3, 4, 5]`).

Comment: Very elegant for a golfing lang

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 16

If there are `N` power strips, then there should be `N-1` separators in the comma-separated input list.  All we need to do is replace the separators with `- 1 +` and arithmetically evaluate:

```
sed s/,/-1+/g|bc
```

Or using the same trick:

## Pure Bash (no external utilities), 19

```
echo $[${1//,/-1+}]
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL (NARS 2000), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

`{1+(+/⍵)-⍴∊⍵}`

Edit: Down to 10 with Lynn's (better) approach.

`{1++/1-⍨⍵}`

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 7 bytes

```
q~:(:+)
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3A(%3A%2B)&input=%5B2%204%206%5D)

Same approach as Lynn's (decrement all, sum, increment). This also works for 8 bytes (and is maybe a bit more interesting):

```
q~{(+}*
```

This folds "decrement, add" over the list. By doing that, the decrement is only applied to all elements except the first, such that we don't need to take care of the increment separately.

Answer (score 3):

## gs2, 5 bytes

(CP437-encoded.)

```
W&Φd'
```

That’s `read-nums dec m1 sum inc`.

Answer (score 3):

### Seriously, 7 bytes

```
,;l@Σ-u
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LDtsQM6jLXU&input=MiwzLDQ)

Explanation:

```
,;l@Σ-u
,        push input
 ;       dupe
  l@     push length (n), swap
    Σ-u  push sum, subtract n, add one
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>60</s> <s>59</s> 55 bytes

```
x;main(s){while(~scanf("%i",&x))s+=x-1;printf("%i",s);}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 6, 14 bytes

```perl6
{1+[+] --«@_}
```

**usage**

```perl6
my &f = {1+[+] --«@_}

say f([2,3,4]) # 7
say f([2,4,6]) # 10
say f([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]) # 1
say f([100,1000,10000]) # 11098
```

Comment: I fully intended to edit my answer to the very same thing ( see the [html comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/1563b7ff-6fad-460b-9e33-f87b7f32bc33/view-source))

Comment: 11 bytes: `{.sum-$_+1}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Mornington Crescent](https://github.com/padarom/esoterpret),  <s>1909 1873</s>  1839 bytes

```
Take Northern Line to Stockwell
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Cannon Street
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Cannon Street
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Turnham Green
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Turnham Green
Take District Line to Notting Hill Gate
Take Circle Line to Notting Hill Gate
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Embankment
Take Northern Line to Stockwell
Take Northern Line to Embankment
Take Circle Line to Temple
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Blackfriars
Take Circle Line to Embankment
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Circle Line to Blackfriars
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Angel
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVXBTsMwDL3vK8IdPoIVtB5gmrQC5xDMGjWxJ9fA5w8PtFZaWxpAlXrNc16c5/eSSIwed0J45RhqByiHQ2ErMGtiKYHR3HkEI2S2Qq76gBAWX/ijd0LsbYvDO6DZ@lqA64Ga08I3nHl2AdLApcWqF8htjHpg9FL24plFJO1LGEAmYkhv7kblYb1nU/Gwjx6Pkg3g/2dYgiM89j7T/cUbY2mjWWkJ/lmFFJY1iajZTe5DMCsr0DuztKrBkd/GZ4WiBmmRlKMOfk5wxl9A3AeYyG1z98oyWFe96htxemFGxO8QbHQnYf2jTSZM89z1TZFnxJ9jI2rV7Tj/GncwlIrBobTA79UY5@z0cd98mCZrPsxc00yX5ok4vFx8Ag)

Comment: "90% of all instructions involve takeing the District Line." It's because District is where all the arithmetic stations are. However, [on TIO, it doesn't seem to work for any of the examples](https://tio.run/##5VXLTgMxDLz3K/wDXIAfYBfUHqCq1MI9RKYbbWJXXgOfX1yqbiWifUjVSpW4ZuyJPfYkiYUCbZXpxgs2Hkn3@42rEZYsWqEQPAdCUIa1sq@/McbZL/4WvLIEd8bxCwnWoVGUpiPmdHCEyyA@4jiwcFQfgUe7QSy0hRYuJbsyBa06IkpHxFabCqJOynJRma@7FOgg32QMBXqmQ/1Xmj/c4eZTqHIJ5kZCk7IsWdWsAYsQI8yd4oVxPavxlN4NTGa@2SjvZfhfgrxhTLuI/3aviuh8/WFvy@llGhxBFrCyXKamd2Umdf@1azxGoEGVhwd11jhzwQNtscshPWk9UxvUZAxrBr20ny6U7ad7C3dw/wM).

Comment: [1873 bytes](https://tio.run/##zVXBTsMwDL3vK8IdPoIWtB5gQlqBcwhmjZrYk2vg84cHWiutLQ1ClXrNc16c5/eSSIwed0J45RgaByiHQ2lrMBtiqYDR3HkEI2S2Qq7@hBBW3/iTd0LsbYfDB6DZ@kaAm5Ga08IPnHt2AdLAzGI9CBQ2Rj0weqkG8dwikvYlDCAzMaQ3d6PysN6zrXjcR49HyUbw/zNk4AiPvS90//QNy3fGykazVhKclWVDIhoHU/gQzNoKDE41rWrUFLfxRaGoUVslJa2HnxOc8ZcQ9wFm8uPS3ZQF6@o3fUVOb9CE@D2CB91J2PxqkxnzvnR9U@SZ8OfUiDp1e86/xh2MpWJ0KB3wdzWmOXt93LdfqsnbL7XQNNOleSYOrxdf) by using shorter line names where possible

Comment: TIO's interpreter has a bug and doesn't implement Turnham Green

Comment: Nice catch. I've sent a PR that fixes it upstream.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 20 bytes

```perl6
put 1+sum --«@*ARGS
```

( You can use `<<` instead of `«` )

#### Usage:

```sh
$ perl6 -e 'put 1+sum --«@*ARGS' 100 1000 10000
11098
```

Comment: « is a Perl operator?

Comment: @immibis Actually it's part of several Perl 6 operators `@arraya »+« @arrayb` `++«@array` `@array».method`  `@array»++` `« a 'space separated' list of words »` Several of those are what is known as Meta operators, in that they combine with other operators. ( Perl 5 doesn't have those operators currently. )

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 23+2=25 or 19+2=21

Requires `-ap` flags:

```
map{$.+=($_-1)}@F;$_=$.
```

Saved in a file and run as

```
perl -ap file.pl
```

EDIT: Another answer, smaller (19+2) but basically copied from dev-null answer:

```
$.+=$_-1for@F;$_=$.
```

Answer (score 2):

### F#, 25 bytes

```
Seq.fold(fun s n->s+n-1)1
```

This is a function that takes in an array/list/sequence of integers and returns the required result.

#### How it works:

`Seq.fold` allows you to apply a function to every element of a sequence while carrying some state around while it does so. The result of the function as applied to the first element will give the state that will be put into the function for the second element, and so forth. For example, to sum up the list `[1; 3; 4; 10]`, you'd write it like this:

```
Seq.fold (fun sum element -> sum + element) 0 [1; 3; 4; 10]
         (       function to apply        ) ^ (sequence to process)
                                     ( initial state )
```

Which would be applied like so:

```
// First, initial state  + first element
0 + 1  = 1
// Then, previous state + next element until the end of the sequence
1 + 3  = 4
4 + 4  = 8
8 + 10 = 18
```

With the last state being the return value of `Seq.fold`.

Answer (score 2):

## , 5 chars / 7 bytes

```
ï⒭+‡_
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=%5B2%2C3%2C4%5D&code=%C3%AF%E2%92%AD%2B%E2%80%A1_)</kbd>

Uses a custom encoding with 10-bit chars (thx @Dennis!). Run `encode('ï⒭+‡_')` in the JS console to get encoded form, and `decode(/*ENCODED TEXT HERE*/)` to decode encoded form.

## Explanation

Translates to Javascript ES6 as:

```
i=>i.reduce(($,_)=>$+--_)
```

Comment: Interesting encoding.

Comment: It works quite nicely, too.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 79 bytes

```
import sys
print(sum(map(lambda x: int(x)-1, sys.stdin.readline().split()))+1)
```

Comment: Looks like you're counting a newline as two bytes. Maybe replace it with a semi-colon to save a byte. A few spaces can be removed too.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 21 + 2 = 23 bytes

```
$a+=$_-1for@F;say++$a
```

Requires `-a` and `-E`:

```
$ perl -aE'$a+=$_-1for@F;say++$a'<<<'2 3 4'
7
```

Comment: You can use the `-a` flag to get `@F` variable with already split elements, and replace -n with -p so you dont'need `say`, reducing it to 21+2: `$a+=$_-1for@F;$_=++$a`

Comment: Using `-p` instead of `say` is the same because I need to use `$_=` anyway.

Comment: @ChatterOne `-a` is a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 30 bytes

```
$*.inject(1){|s,v|s+=v.to_i-1}
```

Simple enough - starting from 1, add up the supplied numbers, each -1 (command line args are in `$*`). Shame `inject` is such a long word.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 19 bytes

```
$args-join'-1+'|iex
```

Note that `1 + p1-1 + p2-1 + ... + pn-1` is equivalent to `p1-1 + p2-1 + ... + pn`.

Takes input as separate command-line arguments with `$args`. We `-join` those together with a `-1+` delimiter to create a string, such as `2-1+3-1+4`. The string is then piped to `Invoke-Expression` (similar to `eval`), and outputs the result.

Answer (score 1):

### Brainfuck, 15 bytes

Assumption: The , operator returns 0 once all input has been exhausted, and there are no extension cords with 0 plugs. Also, the IO needs to be in byte values instead of ASCII character codes.

```
+>,[-[-<+>],]<.
```

Explanation:
This uses 2 registers. A "Value" accumulator register, representing the number of devices that can be plugged in, and a "current cord" register that keeps track of the value of the current cord. It starts off by incrementing the value by 1, for the existing outlet. Then, for each extension cord, it subtracts one from the value since a plug is being taken up, then increments the value by the number of plugs.

Most online interpreters don't operate in raw byte input mode. To test it online, use this code:

```
+>,[->-[>+<-----]>---[-<+>]<[-<->]<[-<+>],]<.
```

Comment: Can I test the program somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, corrected those mistakes. I'm not aware of any online interpreters that operate in byte mode. I can throw together an implementation that subtracts '0' from the inputs that will run on any online interpreter.

Comment: If you want to test out the code, run it here: https://copy.sh/brainfuck/
Don't put spaces in between the numerical values. Unfortunately, since it's operating in ASCII mode, the demo code will only work on single digit values. However, the 15 byte version will work properly on an value <= 255.
After you run it, view the memory dump to view the final value.

Comment: One day BF will have proper standards for expected IO and we'll just be able to say 'using standard 3' instead of e.g. 'input and output are all asciii terminated by null char'.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 17 bytes

Completely straightforward.

```
v->vecsum(v)-#v+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 6

Takes a list of space separated numbers on the command line then sums them all and subtracts the length.

```
1(i)-s
```

How it works:

```
1   # Push 1 to the stack.
(   # Start a list.
 i  # Get command line input.
  ) # End a list.
-   # Subtract the top two elements of the stack. In the case where one of the elements is
    # a list, it does matrix subtraction.
s   # Sum the stack.
    # Print the stack implicitly.
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>24</s> 14 bytes

```
sum(1,scan()-1)
```

Edit: Fixed bug!

Comment: @PålGD it was a bug [untested code posted on phone]

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 10+22=32 bytes

```
s=input();print(sum(s)-len(s)+1)
```

Main issue is not having a default input variable in Python, or implicit printing.

Answer (score 1):

## APL Nars 9 chars

```
{1++/⍵-1}
```

test

```
f←{1++/⍵-1}
  f 2 3 4
7
  f 2 4 6
10
  f 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1
  f 100 1000 10000
11098
```

Answer (score 1):

## [TIS](https://github.com/Phlarx/tis), 93 bytes

Code:

```
@0
MOV ANY ANY
@1
MOV UP ACC
JGZ G
SWP
ADD 1
MOV ACC DOWN
G:SUB 1
MOV ACC ANY
SWP
ADD ANY
SWP
```

Layout:

```
1 2 CC
I1 NUMERIC -
O1 NUMERIC -
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUw5CoAwEOz3FfMBwaiVlTGREMFElCj6A8FO/7/eYDEw975szEVMjR8g3XSBCnHL0EIqRbWZYagfW5Ja44lOH9qPjkzeh/JnXvOv@nLmBCkyxBytLJDg/LQCLjRVZxUi8j9xAA)

Note that this solution requires the list to be terminated by a zero (or more accurately, a non-positive value).

With TIS, we'd need to choose one of the following a) a terminating character, b) a length-prefixed array, or c) a running output for every value. Otherwise, a program would never print any output because there (theoretically) could be more input on the way.

#### Explanation:

Each node has two accumulators, called `ACC` and `BAK`. `BAK` can only be accessed by the `SWP` instruction, which swaps the values in `ACC` and `BAK`. In the following, I will use variables X and Y to track the values more directly. I'll also use Z as shorthand for the entire node 0.

Additionally, each node implicitly loops back to the top when it reaches the bottom.

```
                                  |    Input 0    | Input as whitespace-delimited numbers
                  +--------+------+--------+------+
                  | Node 0 |      | Node 1 |      |
Node 0 is just an +--------+      +--------+      |
extra memory cell | MOV ANY ANY   | MOV UP ACC    | Put input value into X
so we can perform |               | JGZ G         | If X>0, jump to label G
logic on input    |               | SWP           | Swap focus to Y
values easier     |               | ADD 1         | Y++
                  |               | MOV ACC DOWN  | Output the value Y
                  |               |               | (end program -- see note 1 below)
                  |               | G:SUB 1       | Label G: X--
                  |               | MOV ACC ANY   | Z = X (also see note 2 below)
                  |               | SWP           | Swap focus to Y
                  |               | ADD ANY       | Y += Z (also see note 2 below)
                  |               | SWP           | Swap focus to X
                  +---------------+---------------+
                                  |   Output 0    | Output as whitespace-delimited numbers
```

*Note 1, regarding the termination of this program:*

The TIS emulator I am using here will terminate the program once there is no more active processing. The most common reason for getting into such a state is to exhaust all available input, though things like deadlocks can also get us to this state.

Once the value in this program has been output, calculation will continue on at label G, mangling the data in the registers (it forgets which register is X and which is Y). However, it will quickly return to the line that reads input, and because the input will now be exhausted, the program will terminate.

Some minor modifications may be made to adjust the program to handle data after the terminator:

- Adding the instruction `HCF` just before the label G will cause the program to forcibly terminate at this point instead of relying on input exhaustion.
- Adding the instructions `SWP` and `JRO -99` just before the label G will cause the program to return to a good state, then jump back to top (relative jumps can't wrap, so anything further than -15 will always go to the top line; offhand, I think -7 is the exact value needed here). This turns the terminator into a 'print' instruction instead.
- The value Y could be reset to zero, in addition to the jump described above, to treat extended input as two or more distinct invocations.

*Note 2, regarding the use of `ANY` in node 1:*

The use of `ANY` on the two marked lines of Node 1 is possible due to an implementation detail (this quirk is true in both this emulator and in the original Zachtronics game).

When `ANY` is used as the source, it looks at the node's neighbors in this order: `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `UP`, `DOWN`. When `ANY` is used as the destination, it looks at the neighbors in this order: `UP`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `DOWN`. (The destination ordering is a consequence of both the source ordering and the order in which the nodes are run.)

Of course, the nodes not only need to be present but also be ready to send/receive a value to be selected.

Since `LEFT` appears before `UP` as a source, and before `DOWN` as a destination, `ANY` will always be `LEFT` in this case.

To make this program "implementation-independent", simply replace those two `ANY`s with `LEFT`s.

The reason that the `ANY`s in node 0 are of no concern is that node 0 only ever has one neighbor to talk to.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 6 bytes

```
1+/-1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/31BbX9dQ29DAQAGIIYTB//8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 27 bytes

```
	dot dip +
+
	
	dot dab dot
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/58zJb9EISWzQEGbS5uLkwvCTUxSANL///83NDAAYQhhAAA)

Explanation:

The `main` function (top line, implicitly named `main`) is called at the start of the program. It contains this command:

```
dot dip +
```

`+` is called on the tuple given as separate command-line arguments. This is `+`:

```
dot dab dot
```

The empty command simply returns the argument as-is. The other command, `dot dab dot`, returns `0`. It has to be able to convert any given tuple to zero, so here's how this does it, right-to-left:

First of all, `dot` returns a 1-element tuple that contains the sum of the input's elements. The actual sum doesn't matter here, what matters is that `dot` will always return a 1-element tuple, so that we can use `dab` on it to remove its first (i.e. only) element, since there's no built-in to empty a tuple. The sum of an empty tuple is `0`, so we just `dot` this empty tuple to return the singleton `0`.

After this process, the two results of the `+` function (the input and `0`) are implicitly concatenated. We now return to `main`.

The `dip` command will decrement each positive number by 1, and convert each 0 to 1, in `+`'s result. This will decrement each number of available outlets, and also increment the final 0, so we don't miss a free outlet.

Finally, the tuple will be `dot`ted again, so we're computing the number of available outlets over all of the power strips, minus the number of power strips, plus one (no strip occupies an outlet of the last strip).

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 40 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(1+(-(reduce'+ x)(length x))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJlXoqDxXyMnMTcpJVGjQlPDUFtDV6MoNaU0OVVdWwEokJOal16SAWQBwX91DSMFEwUzEBMA)