# Without using numbers, Calculate Pi

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, pi

<sup>[Inspired by Nicola Sap's Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171168/without-using-numbers-get-the-highest-salary-you-can-but-dont-exaggerate)</sup>

## Goal

Your challenge is to simply produce π with 2<sup>32</sup>-1 digits. However today's twist, like the title implies, is to produce it without using any numbers or any π constants in your source-code.

## Input/Output

Your program will not be provided usable input. It can output in any reasonable format.

## Rules

- Standard Loop-Holes forbidden
- You cannot use numbers in your source code nor can you use a pi constant if it exists. If your language also has tau defined as 2pi, that's also banned. Numbers are in the range [0-9]
- <s>You must output as many digits as you can</s> You must output 2^32-1 digits of pi, including the 3. (This has been changed due to the arbitrary nature of the original task)
- Your Program must terminate, or at least theoretically terminate given enough time. Crashing is an acceptable way to terminate.

## Scoring

This is code golf so shortest answer wins.

[A Million Digits of Pi for your use](https://www.piday.org/million/)

Comment: Just acknowledging that it's been done to death doesn't mean that you're not killing it more.

Comment: How do you define numbers?

Comment: @JoKing It might prove to be a fresh enough spin to be interesting. If not, so it goes. Besides, if I didn't say it, someone else would've. Also added

Comment: Given that there are algorithms for computing pi to an arbitrary precision I think there need to be some more limits imposed on the problem. Otherwise the winner is just whoever uses the largest target precision. Working around the no-numbers restriction just requires casting `char` to `int`

Comment: @user202729 Yeah, I overlooked that aspect. I guess to salvage this, the goal shall be changed to generating 2^32-1 digits

Comment: It's unfortunate that Shakespeare doesn't have arbitrary precision, or else the Shakespeare Programming Language would be a shoo-in.

Comment: @JosiahRyanW I guess implementing arbitrary precision in SPL is not very hard. But how is that related?

Comment: @user202729 Shakespeare doesn't have numbers in its source code anyways.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 67 bytes

```perl6
{$!=.FatRat²/$!+$_+$_-?e}for ²…¹;say substr ⁴/$!,^²³²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/79aRdFWzy2xJCix5NAmfRVFbZV4INK1T61Nyy9S@DChZfOhTY8alh3aaV2cWKlQXJpUXFKk8KhxC1CpTtyhTYeA0v//AwA)

Takes a *very* long time to compute. As an example here's an altered version that only prints the first [1000 digits](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/79aRdFWzy2xJCix5NAmfRVFbZV4INK1T61Nyy9SMDIwMHjUsOzQTuvixEqF4tKk4pIihUeNW4AKdeIMDQyM/v8HAA).

Comment: Can you not remove the braces?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>42</s> 39 bytes

`N[Log[-(d=I/I)]/I,((c=d+d)^c^c^c)^c-d]&`

<s>Output</s> Returns exactly 4294967295 digits as requested.

If more digits were allowed, then by outputting 7.76e17 digits (if even possible lol), 26 bytes would be possible:

`N[Log[-E/E]/I,E^(E^E*E)]&`

#### Sorry but `Pi = Ln(-1)/i`.

Comment: The OP has changed the challenge to produce `2^32-1` digits of Pi

Comment: @JoKing You mean `2147483647` digits exactly?

Comment: `4,294,967,295` actually.

Comment: @Veskah I though it was `2^(32-1)-1` lol

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>70</s> 85 bytes

```
;''!..):t{](..+.*:a@~@*\a(*@)\@}t.+.+t+:T t..*.*t*?(:b?*@;\{.@[\].~/\~%T*@}b*;;]("."@
```

*+15 bytes because I can't read.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoMwEAXQq1ihGH/gd58snENk52ShgqUgWOrsxFw99i3fe9/WY/l9vlZr7LoH2Qc7syM9ESYpAp0cpFe57H/efEiNkSAMgwvzAIl6UkbNLC8tzwS5ZsSYXctWar0B)

Or, actually, don't. [Try this online instead](https://tio.run/##DcmxCoAgEADQXykh0hOuXYfuI9w6BwuKICjqtshfN9f3tvNYn@XeLynF932LaJy8USNaBJcoE3DSQIbpk2pWrAuN1JtHIM8v0sQR88C5C0DfDN5HrVBRKT8), which calculates 4 digits.